# Types of Meditation in Theravada Buddhism

Tags: theravada, meditation

How many types of meditation are there in Theravada Buddhism? Could you also provide a list of them as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least forty:

1. Earth device

   Water device

   Fire device

   Air or wind device

   Blue device

   Yellow device

   Red device

   White device

   Space device

   Consciousness device

   A corpse that is bloated

   A corpse that is livid (has patchy discoloration)

   A corpse that is festering (trickling with pus in broken places)

   A corpse that is cut up

   A corpse that is gnawed

   A corpse that is scattered

   A corpse that is hacked and scattered

   A corpse that is bleeding

   A corpse that is worm-infested

   A corpse that is a skeleton

   Contemplation of the Buddha

   Contemplation of the Dhamma

   Contemplation of the Sangha

   Contemplation of Virtue

   Contemplation of Charity

   Contemplation of the Devas

   Mindfulness of Death

   Mindfulness of the Physical Body

   Mindfulness with Breathing

   Contemplation of Calmness

   Loving-kindness

   Compassion

   Sympathy

   Equanimity

   Sphere of Infinity of Space

   Sphere of Infinite Consciousness

   Sphere of No-thingness

   Sphere of Neither Perception nor Non-Perception

   Contemplation of the loathsomeness of food

   Analysis of the four physical elements

http://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php?title=40_meditation_subjects

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how are some of these types of meditation? For example, 'a corpse that is bleeding'.

Comment: https://suttacentral.net/en/dn22 may help! :)

Comment: @IlyaGrushevskiy thank you so much! That definitely helped. I have been looking for this for so long. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The meditation subjects are called [Kammaṭṭhāna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamma%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na). There are 40 of them.

Most of these are collected in the following books:

- [Visuddhimagga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visuddhimagga)
- [Vimuttimagga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimuttimagga)

Also you might want to read [Knowing and Seeing](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books13/Pa-Auk-Sayadaw_Knowing-and-Seeing-4th-Ed-2010.pdf) by Pa Auk Sayadaw which glosses over many of matter.

Looking at the size of these manual it is difficult to give introduction to all in one answer.

But in ascese all have the similar goal. That is to:

- scrub the latent tendencies (anusaya), [Kleshas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleshas_(Buddhism)) or unwholesome roots
- remove the corruptions of insight (vipallasa) and understand the [three marks of existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence)

with ever way you understand better.

In studying meditation from any of the above sources it is wise to treat them as secondary source and compair with the [Tripitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) which is the primary source.